# What is the name for the type of photography where the subject is close-up?

Tags: macro, terminology

I believe there is a name for this particular type of photography where the subject is close-up such as the below examples:-

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to search for photography like this on the web but unsure of the correct terminology to use. Sorry for not being able to make my question any clearer.

Comment: Some would consider them "macro" - but, as the image is unlikely to be 1:1 (or greater) on the film/sensor, that term is a little incorrect here.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th - Yes, that's good enough for me, this returns loads of what I'm after and is exactly what stores online (i.e [here](http://www.fotoviva.co.uk/macro-wall-art)) appear to label this type of photography as. Thanks (if you add as an answer, I'll accept it when I can).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the two photos you shared, I can claim that you are interested in **macro photography**.

**Macro** gives you the opportunity to take a photo of an object far closer than a **close up**. There are some **subclasses**, such as the already mentioned here. **But in general the main category is macro. Macro can achieved with macro lenses, like Canon 100mm 2.8. Don't confuse macro with close-up: a true macro photo has magnification at least 1:1.**

However, for **super macro** you can use lenses, like Canon MP-E 65mm 2.8, in case you want to get even closer. The particular lens has magnification up to 5:1.

The 1:1 means that it is a **true representation** of what you are photographing, not a magnification of lets say 5 times bigger than the object really is, comparing always the image sensor with the object. For more details on magnification, I would suggest you reading here: http://www.dpreview.com/articles/6519974919/macro-photography-understanding-magnification

Not to confuse you, there is a debate about if a true macro is 1:1 only or 1:1 and more. Some say that macro is only 1:1, others than it is 1:1 and more, like 2:1. But don't let this confuse you any further.

**Just keep in mind that with a true macro lens you must have magnification 1:1 and not less than this.**

There are several sites/books, focused on macro photography, which involve specific techniques and photos you can be inspired by.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have edited the content to make it even more understandable. Hope that helps you even more!

Comment: Also, there is debate on whether it's the actual sensor size, a theoretical 24x36 sensor size, or the final screenview/printout that should be compared to the subject size. Thus, there are at least six different definitions for what "true macro" means. :)

Comment: I haven't heard about this debate. From what I know, we are talking about the actual image sensor, not the screenview. :) After all, we are interested in the image sensor and the comparison should be made between the object and the image sensor. The screenview serves only as a ''tool'' to see the result.

Comment: @Guffa: I hadn't ever heard that the debate involved the final screen/printout size. I do believe there is some debate about whether 1:1 only refers to magnification with a FF (36x24mm) sensor, or whether it also means an APS-C sensor. In the case of the Canon 100mm f/2.8 lens, it's an EF lens, so the 1:1 designation would probably require a FF sensor to be true. The term macro generally means "large" or "great", usually in reference to something as large as or larger than "in real life", in contrast with micro which means smaller than in real life.

Comment: Based on the raw definition of the term macro, I think that means any lens that offers at least 1:1 magnification of your subject ON THE SENSOR would qualify for the term. That means lenses with 2:1, 3:1, 5:1, 10:1, etc. magnification factors would all qualify. The 1:1 designation is the minimum, since at that magnification your subject, ON THE SENSOR, is the same size as in real life (enlarged onto a computer screen or in print, it would be much larger than in real life). If your using a FF lens on a crop sensor, then the 1:1 designation is a bit dubious...it would really depend on exactly...

Comment: ...how you framed your subject. If you use a 1:1 macro lens meant for FF on an APS-C sensor, for example, it would really only achieve 1:1 magnification if you used it at the MFD...in which case your subject might be cropped a bit relative to the exact same usage with a FF sensor. If you pull the lens back a bit on a cropped sensor, in order to fully frame your subject (say a snail or an insect), then your now below the 1:1 magnification level, and you are no longer "macro".

Comment: The magnification is not really a thing depending on the sensor. Manification remains the same, as the crop factor has nothing to do with magnification. The crop factor does not magnify the scene, meaning that the field of view on a 1.6x crop sensor is not magnified. So the magnification is not dependable on the sensor size of a particular camera. However, let's keep it simple, as the person that asked the question was interested in the kind of photography. Magnification is an extra here.

Comment: @Morpho: You could just as well say that the sensor is just a tool for creating the result, and the result is the final image.

Comment: @jrista: You only have to go as far as the wikipedia page to see the different views mentioned. It even says that the printout is more commonly used than the sensor size as comparison. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_photography

Comment: @Guffa: I strongly dispute whoever wrote that Wikipedia page, then. I've had too many conversations about macro photography to count since I first started photography. I have NEVER heard of anyone referring to print or screen magnification when talking about the magnification ratio of a lens. Magnification ratios of lenses has always referred to the reproduction size on the sensor. Every lens has a magnification ratio, commonly around 1:4 - 1:10...that magnification is always relative to the sensor. When Canon puts 1:1 on their lens, that SPECIFICALLY means relative to the sensor.

Comment: Your wikipedia article even backs this up: `The ratio of the subject size on the film plane (or sensor plane) to the actual subject size is known as the reproduction ratio. Likewise, a macro lens is classically a lens capable of reproduction ratios greater than 1:1, although it often refers to any lens with a large reproduction ratio, despite rarely exceeding 1:1.` Classically, technically, the 1:1 designation used on macro lenses has to do with the reproduction ratio of a real life subject relative to the sensor. Colloquially, some people also consider 1:2 lenses to be "macro", however...

Comment: ...technically speaking, that would not be true, since the reproduced image of your real-life subject is SMALLER than in real life, not the same size or larger. It would only be macro when considering print size, however print size is arbitrary, where as sensor reproduction ratio (assuming FF) is fixed (and therefor the only logical proper interpretation of an X:Y ratio printed on a lens). When your lens magnification/reproduction ratio gets to around 1:3 or more, it rapidly becomes very difficult to reproduce a life-sized image, even in print, unless you are printing extremely large.

Comment: @Morpho: I agree, crop factor is not technically part of magnification. I believe I was clear enough in my description of framing, however, that I did not explain anything inaccurately regarding reproduction ratio within the image circle. If you FRAME your macro subjects the same with the same macro lens on FF and APS-C, the APS-C would technically not be reproduced 1:1. That is exactly __because__ of what you said, not in *contrast* to it.

Comment: We should not compare the sensor size with the screen view. 1:1 is the real representation, comparing the width of the sensor with the width of the object. In my post there is a site, that explains well what magnification includes. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **"High Speed Photo"**

Below are some examples which resembles with your example photos.
http://photography.tutsplus.com/articles/freezing-time-80-inspiring-examples-of-high-speed-photography--photo-340

Comment: While the second may be high-speed photography, snails aren't famous for moving quickly!

Comment: Macro photography seems to be a better match as to what I was after although the high speed photography at that article is equally pretty awesome. Thanks.